# Business Central - Docker Build failed with exit code -1

Tags: docker, containers, powershell-3.0, windows-server, dynamics-business-central

## Describe the issue

I encountered this error while trying to deploy a new BC instance.

```
Docker Build failed with exit code -1
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\BcContainerHelper\4.0.14\ContainerHandling\New-NavImage.ps1:671 char:25
+ ...              throw "Docker Build failed with exit code $LastExitCode"
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Docker Build failed with exit code -1:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Docker Build failed with exit code -1
```

## Scripts used to create container and cause the issue

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -force

install-packageprovider -name NuGet -minimumversion 2.8.5.201 -force
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName containers -All

Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Repository PSGallery -Force
install-module bccontainerhelper -force



Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -force

install-module bccontainerhelper -force

$vm_fqdn = 
$email =

Setup-TraefikContainerForBcContainers -PublicDnsName $vm_fqdn -ContactEMailForLetsEncrypt $email

$bc_admin = 
$bc_username = 
$container_name =
$artifact = "https://bcartifacts.azureedge.net/sandbox/21.5.53619.54509/fr"
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $bc_admin -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($bc_username,$securePassword)
$auth = 'UserPassword'

New-BcContainer `
    -accept_eula `
    -containerName $container_name `
    -credential $credential `
    -auth $auth `
    -artifactUrl $artifact `
    -useTraefik true
```

## Full output of scripts

```
BcContainerHelper version 4.0.14
BC.HelperFunctions emits usage statistics telemetry to Microsoft
BcContainerHelper is version 4.0.14
BcContainerHelper is running as administrator
HyperV is Enabled
UsePsSession is True
Host is Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Datacenter - 10.0.17763.4131
Docker Client Version is 20.10.9
Docker Server Version is 20.10.9
Removing Desktop shortcuts
Fetching all docker images
Fetching all docker volumes
ArtifactUrl and ImageName specified
Building multitenant image true:sandbox-21.5.53619.54509-fr-mt based on mcr.microsoft.com/businesscentral:10.0.17763.4131 with https://bcartifacts.azureedge.net/sandbox/2
1.5.53619.54509/fr
Pulling latest image mcr.microsoft.com/businesscentral:10.0.17763.4131
10.0.17763.4131: Pulling from businesscentral
Digest: sha256:bdbd1e7efedf67a3804abc61f1da55a1396b04ca86dadccc334ffdbaf339521e
Status: Image is up to date for mcr.microsoft.com/businesscentral:10.0.17763.4131
mcr.microsoft.com/businesscentral:10.0.17763.4131
Generic Tag: 1.0.2.14
Container OS Version: 10.0.17763.4131 (ltsc2019)
Host OS Version: 10.0.17763.4131 (ltsc2019)
Using process isolation
Files in c:\bcartifacts.cache\htjr2wpq.pq3\my:
Copying Platform Artifacts
c:\bcartifacts.cache\sandbox\21.5.53619.54509\platform
Copying Database
Copying Licensefile
Copying ConfigurationPackages
C:\bcartifacts.cache\sandbox\21.5.53619.54509\fr\ConfigurationPackages
Copying Extensions
C:\bcartifacts.cache\sandbox\21.5.53619.54509\fr\Extensions
Copying Applications.FR
C:\bcartifacts.cache\sandbox\21.5.53619.54509\fr\Applications.FR
c:\bcartifacts.cache\htjr2wpq.pq3
New-Bcimage Telemetry Correlation Id: 1ee7df2d-d115-4345-8668-8014f2170276
New-BcContainer Telemetry Correlation Id: 66145d3c-9e74-4336-bb01-e70e5ab1ee1f
Docker Build failed with exit code -1
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\BcContainerHelper\4.0.14\ContainerHandling\New-NavImage.ps1:671 char:25
+ ...              throw "Docker Build failed with exit code $LastExitCode"
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Docker Build failed with exit code -1:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Docker Build failed with exit code -1
```

## Additional context

Windows Server 2019 1809
It happen all the time.

```
Docker version:

Client: Mirantis Container Runtime
 Version:           20.10.9
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.12m2
 Git commit:        591094d
 Built:             12/21/2021 21:34:30
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Mirantis Container Runtime
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.9
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.16.12m2
  Git commit:       9b96ce992b
  Built:            12/21/2021 21:33:06
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

OS is up to date. I've tried to remove the docker images and restart the script. Same issue
I've tried to remove the businesscentral.cache and restart the script, same issue.
The process isn't blocked by the antivirus.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In my experience, the same error was indeed caused by antivirus software (company network).